# Grails application failed to run in GoogleAppEngine due to HashMap$Entry ClassNotFound error

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, groovy

I am trying to port my Grails project to GAE, now it has the Cloud SQL support. I did not use the Grails App Engine Plugin because it doesn't appear to support Cloud SQL (after all it's fairly new). I was able to manage to get my Grails project running on localhost under Google Java Development Server and everything is functioning. But after I upload the app to Google Appspot, the app failed to initialize citing ClassNotFound for java.util.HashMap$Entry. My gut feeling is that the groovy enhanced Hashmap class used some features not allowed by App Engine and thus prevented it from loading. But i'm a groovy newbie so don't really know where to start digging in Groovy.

Stacktrace:

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@92af24{/,/base/data/home/apps/fluentifyme/1.357352126538464031}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class groovy.util.ConfigObject
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class groovy.util.ConfigObject
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:34)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have bumped into [this reported bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4950) related to ConfigSlurper and the security restrictions on GAE. As the bug suggests, you might be able to switch to using JsonSlurper to work around this problem.